# in react-navigation, how can I prevent the AppBar to be fixed top ? I want it to disappear when I scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I am working with react-navigation 5.x and I want my AppBar to disappear when I scroll down.

This is how my navigation looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

export default function createAppContainer(AppNavigator) {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createDrawerNavigator();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
  return ({ AppBar, DrawerContent, ...rest }) => (
    <Navigator drawerContent={DrawerContent}>
      <Screen
        name="inner-drawer"
        component={(props) => (
          <AppNavigator
            headerMode="screen"
            screenOptions={AppBar ? {
              header: AppBar,
            } : undefined}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
        {...rest}
      />
    </Navigator>
  );
}
```

In react-navigation, how can I prevent the AppBar to be fixed top?

Comment: try combination with `Scrollview property` [`onScroll = e => e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.27/scrollview#onscroll) and `static navigationOptions = { header: // null or your header}`. You may also play around `this.props.navigation.setParams`. This works on both web as well as native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Animated.diffClamp()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#diffclamp) as the documentation said:

> This is useful with scroll events, for example, to show the navbar when scrolling up and to hide it when scrolling down.

Comment: I see. This is a nice effect, but I was looking for something more simple that could work for both web and native. Like `position: static` and `position: fixed`. I up vote still it's valuable information

Comment: you need to implement your own animation then and your own app bar you have to hide the app bar.